# sql server inner joins. Creating View or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Users and messages: [image]

How i can make select full the conversation between the two users?

for example if user #1 send message: "How Are you" to user #2 and then #2 answered "Fine and you?" how then select something like this?

[image]

Thanks and sorry my English is poor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(untested ... ;)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetConversation 
( 
  @user1 BIGINT 
  ,@user2 BIGINT
) 
AS 
Select [FromUserID], Date, Text from Messages WHERE [FromUserID] in (@user1,@user2) AND [ToUserID] in (@user1,@user2) ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Note, the 'Users' table is only needed if you would want to map specific data from the users. For example: showing the user names instead of their ID. You will archieve this with a simple JOIN.

@Edit: didn't notice the 'stored procedure' in the question title at the first.